# I'm not sure how to fix my two errors before compiling my program

Tags: c++

I have been stuck at this brick wall for a few hours now and I'm not sure what to do with my code to fix these errors. I'm trying to get a class average out of given homework scores from a text file. I was able to get the program to read the text file, but I couldn't get the program to calculate the averages.

Here are the errors.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'readFile'
   readFile(showAverage);
   ^~~~~~~~

pa05.cpp:42:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int (int, int, int)' to 'ifstream &' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char> &') for 1st argument
void readFile(ifstream &someFile)
```

Here is my code so far:

File: pa05.cpp

```
// @author Avery Baumann
// @version October 9 2014
// Programming Assignment 05
// This program calculates students' average
// homework scores and their grades and displays it in a nicely
// formatted table. The data is read from a file in order to display it.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void readFile(ifstream&);       //Function prototype
int showAverage (int homeworkOne, int homeworkTwo, int homeworkThree);
int homeworkAverage;
int homeworkOne;
int homeworkTwo;
int homeworkThree;

int main()
{
    ifstream dataIn;

    dataIn.open("/home/shared/cs135/pa05data.txt");
    if (dataIn.fail())
        cout << "Error opening data file.\n";
    else
    {   readFile(dataIn);
        dataIn.close();
    }
    showAverage (homeworkOne, homeworkTwo, homeworkThree);
    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************
*                    readFile                          *
* This function reads and displays the contents of the *
* input file whose file stream object is passed to it. *
********************************************************/

void readFile(ifstream &someFile)
{
    int homeworkOne;
    int homeworkTwo;
    int homeworkThree;
    string student;

    while (someFile)
    {   someFile >> student >> homeworkOne >> homeworkTwo >> homeworkThree;
        cout << student << "  "
             << homeworkOne << "  "
             << homeworkTwo << "  "
             << homeworkThree << "  "
   }
}

/*******************************************************
*                      showAverage                     *
* This function calculates the average of the three    *
* homework scores for each student                     *
********************************************************/

int showAverage(int homeworkOne, int homeworkTwo, int homeworkThree)
{
   int hwAverage;
   readFile(showAverage);

   hwAverage = (homeworkOne + homeworkTwo + homeworkThree) / 2.0;
      cout << hwAverage << "  "
           << endl;

}
```

Comment: So, what is that `readFile(showAverage)` supposed to mean? What were you trying to do by passing one function to another?

Comment: just take out the line `readFile(showAverage);`  . You also need to fix `readFile` so that it saves to the global variables, not to your local copies (which are destroyed when `readFile` ends)

Comment: also you need to reorganize the code in `main()` so that you do not call `showAverage` when the file failed to open.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are using the function `void readFile(ifstream&);` which takes an object of `fstream` , so in part

```
{
    int hwAverage;   
    readFile(showAverage);

    hwAverage = (homeworkOne + homeworkTwo + homeworkThree) / 2.0;

    cout << hwAverage << "  "
         << endl;
}
```

look at the function `readFile` that which parameters you are giving to it. What is `showAverage` in function `readFile(showAverage);`
you must have to pass an `ifstream` object to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function prototype:

```
void readFile(ifstream&);
```

The function accepts a single parameter of type `ifstream`. You call it like this:

```
readFile(showAverage);
```

Since `showAverage` is a function and not an `ifstream`, the code is invalid.

Your `readFile` function reads the file and outputs values to standard output. But the values that were read are lost when `readFile` returns. You no longer have access to them.

So, you want to retain those values. You should put the values that are read into a struct and return it from `readFile`. That way you make the values available outside `readFile`. Then you can pass that struct to `showAverage`.